# alignment requirements for ARM64 ELF executables run in QEMU assembled by GAS

Tags: arm, clang, elf, qemu, gnu-assembler

I have this ARM64 program which assembles but segfaults immediately when I run it:

```
// GNU Assembler, ARM64 Linux

.bss

.lcomm ARRAY, 16

.text

.global _start

_start:
    mov x8, 93 // exit sys num
    mov x0, 0 // success
    svc 0
```

From brute-force trial & error I managed to fix it by adding this line:

```
// GNU Assembler, ARM64 Linux

.bss

.lcomm ARRAY, 16

.p2align 12 // why?

.text

.global _start

_start:
    mov x8, 93 // exit sys num
    mov x0, 0 // success
    svc 0
```

It only works with `.p2align 12` (equivalent to `.balign 4096`) or higher, otherwise it still segfaults with values of `.p2align 11` or lower. I understand the padding is likely fixing some misalignment issue, but I don't understand why it must be such a large value, as virtually every other ARM64 example I've seen, both hand-written and produced by compilers, usually inserts just a `.p2align 2` before the `.text` section so why do I need `.p2align 12` for my tiny program?

Furthermore, I noticed the required size of the padding is inversely-proportional to the length of the `.text` section. For tiny programs like the one above `.p2align 12` is required to make them run without segfaulting, however the longer the `.text` section becomes the smaller I can make the padding, and for programs which have thousands of instructions I don't need to add any padding at all!

I'm on an x86_64 macOS machine but I'm compiling and running these programs inside of a Docker container which is built from this Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install clang qemu gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu
```

I'm compiling and running the ARM64 programs with:

```
clang -nostdlib -fno-integrated-as -target aarch64-linux-gnu -s program.s -o program.out && ./program.out
```

I feel like I'm missing some crucial piece of information regarding GAS, QEMU, ARM64, or ELF executables but I have no clue what it is.

Comment: It assembles and runs without error on a native aarch64-linux machine.  This may be a qemu bug or limitation.

Comment: I don't see any docker or qemu commands being invoked in your command: `clang -nostdlib -fno-integrated-as -target aarch64-linux-gnu -s program.s -o program.out && ./program.out`. I would assume your docker container is running Ubuntu Focal x86_64, and would therefore expect qemu-system-aarch4 to be used for running your program into a aarch64 Linux distro. Am I missing something ?

Comment: @Frant I'm running the `clang` command from inside the Ubuntu 20.04 x86_64 Docker container. The compiled aarch64 ELF program runs without any additional command line arguments, so I'm assuming Ubuntu recognizes the program is an aarch64 ELF file and automatically launches it with QEMU as a CPU emulation layer. I could be wrong though, I don't know how else x86_64 Ubuntu runs aarch64 ELF files.

Comment: Your assumptions are not valid IMHO: you cannot execute an aarch64 ELF executable in Ubuntu Focal out of the box. I am getting the following error by executing program.out in the container (executed `docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/bash qemu-docker:1.0`) `bash: ./program.out: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`
I cannot understand why you are not getting this error. I was able to execute your program only after having installed the `qemu-user` package, and by executing the command: `qemu-aarch64 program.out`

Comment: But  you could execute directly en aarch64 elf executable using binfmt and qemu-arm64-static, using the following configuration:
`:qemu-arm64:M::\x7fELF\x02\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\xb7:\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xfe\xff\xff:/usr/local/bin/qemu-aarch64:OC` - you would have to replace `/usr/local/bin/qemu-aarch64` by  the path to your static qemu-aarch64

Comment: @Frant --

I just uninstalled `qemu` and I can still run the aarch64 ELF file somehow. Now I'm even more confused so I made a new question on AskUnbuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1294500/how-does-x86-64-ubuntu-20-04-run-aarch64-elf-executables --

Anyway, I tried installing `qemu-user` and ran `qemu-aarch64 program.out` and it still segfaults if the `.p2align 12` directive is not included, so the the problem seems to persist regardless of whether I use QEMU or not.

Comment: The _start address of a standard binary is 4k, which is one page and provide the ability to detect writes/read to address zero (or structure indexes up to 4k). ie, the NULL pointer.  Have you set `_start` or are you using a default?  If you don't have a linker file, then your tools may put `.text` right after `.bss`.  You have to examine the elf or a map file.

Comment: @pretzelhammer: I had forgot to mention that yes, the first version was causing a segfault, but not the second one.

Comment: @artless noise: I just checked, and it seems .bss is located after .text:

 1 .text         0000000c  000000000040010c  000000000040010c  0000010c  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
  2 .bss          00000010  0000000000410118  0000000000410118  00000118  2**3
`                  ALLOC

Comment: @artlessnoise I examined `program.out` with a disassembler and it seems that the `.bss` section is always being placed after the `.text` section. I'm not doing anything to modify the location of the `_start` address so I'm assuming it's being set to whatever the default is by GAS / clang

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QEMU is getting confused by the program header for your data section:

```
    LOAD off    0x00000000000000c0 vaddr 0x00000000004100c0 paddr 0x00000000004100c0 align 2**16
         filesz 0x0000000000000000 memsz 0x0000000000000010 flags rw-
```

and is failing to actually mmap some writeable memory at that address; the segfault is coming from QEMU itself when it tries to memset() the BSS to zero.

Since the program runs fine on a real AArch64 Linux kernel, this is a QEMU bug. I've reported it [to the upstream mailing list](https://lore.kernel.org/qemu-devel/CAFEAcA_=RGziK6H4Pip+heE3JfjTYaZgrTgkwM=tNTwsqvuLfg@mail.gmail.com/T/#u) so we'll see if anybody comes up with a fix.